# AWS aurora mysql is restarted unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws, aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

In our system
one of aurora mysql instances was't available for short period.
because this instance suddenly restarted at 08/14/2019 3:56JST.

we already checked error log for aurora.
but i found restarting log only.
at the same day,connection error happened many times.
because our application couldn't connect aurora due to the above things.

we guess some failed happend at aurora.but we don have any info.

what things happened?
and does anyone know how to investigate this problem?

Comment: i would like to check when maintenace is held.

Comment: i can see the schedule for next maintenance.but it doesn't has any past history